# Alterar cor da celula de acordo com o resultado?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Sou iniciante nesse universo, e estou travado no meu desenvolvimento em um função simples da qual não consigo compreender. Esse código abaixo recebe um valor do banco, e eu gostaria que na célula cor, o background mudasse conforme valor, por exemplo se o campo `for = 1` então a célula ficara ***verde***.

```
  <tbody>
    @foreach($estoques as $row)

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ $row->id }}</th>
      <td>{{ $row->categoria->nome }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->cor }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->produto }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->marca }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->qtd }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->observacao  }}</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o código na sua `tr` perguntando para o campo (*foi colocado* `$row->cor`*, mas você pode alterar isso*) e se a `cor == 1` ele coloca um `style` na `tr`.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($estoques as $row)
    <tr>

      <th scope="row">{{ $row->id }}</th>
      <td>{{ $row->categoria->nome }}</td>
      <td<?php if ($row->cor == 2) {echo ' style="background-color:green;"';}?>>{{ $row->cor }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->produto }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->marca }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->qtd }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->observacao  }}</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo, consegui avançar no meu desenvolvimento graças a ti, só tive que fazer esta leve alteração para que funciona-se apenas na linha especifica

    <tbody>
    @foreach($estoques as $row)
    <tr>

      <th scope="row">{{ $row->id }}</th>
      <td>{{ $row->categoria->nome }}</td>
      <td<?php if ($row->cor == 2) {echo ' style="background-color:green;"';}?>>{{ $row->cor }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->produto }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->marca }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->qtd }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->observacao  }}</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach

Comment: @leonardosilva blz!